# How to clear contents of selected cells in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use mouse to drag a selection area in some `JTable` cells, the selection area is the yellow, so can anyone told me exactly how to clear the contents of selected cells by pressing  "Delete" key in keyboard or a `JButton`?

The captured pic of selected cells:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FvkU.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `Acton` to find the selected cells and clear the text. The easiest way is to loop through each cell in the table.

The basics of the `Action` would be something like:

```
Action clearAction = new Action()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for (each row in the table)
            for (each column in the row)
                if (table.isCellSelected(...))
                   table.setValueAt("", ...);
    }
}
```

Then you create a button to invoke the Action:

```
JButton clearButton = new JButton( "Clear" );
clearButton.addActionListener( clearAction );
```

If you also want to use the Delete key then you can use `Key Bindings` to share the same Action.

The basic logic to add a new Key Binding to the JTable would be:

```
String keyStrokeAndKey = "DELETE";
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStrokeAndKey);
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(keyStroke, keyStrokeAndKey);
table.getActionMap().put(keyStrokeAndKey, action);
```

Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for more information.

Comment: thanks first !    I got ideas from your answers and i make it out by my way, i use it in the keypress event.